# if statements to look at different worksheets and cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I have a document with a large amount of data, and various formulas from countif to =if etc.  However, In one particular worksheet cell b2 gets information directly from another cell in another sheet using the simple (='sheet2'!b2) formula.  Now i want the cell underneath to read whats in b2, and dependant upon what it says (either Corrective Actions, Guidance or No Action) for it to look into a final sheet at a cell i want to determine, so if b2 says Corrective action, i want to look in sheet4!B4, if it says Guidance i want to look at sheet4!C4, and of it says No action, to look at Sheet4!D4  I have tried numerous times, but get the error #NAME?  please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple nested `if` should do that:

```
=if(b2="Corrective Actions", Sheet4!B4, if(b2="Guidance", Sheet4!C4, if("No Action", Sheet4!D4, "")))
```

As for your error on your current attempt. It's hard to diagnose without seeing what formula you are using, but `#NAME` errors mean that whatever formula (`if`, `sum`, `countif`, etc) you are attempting to use, doesn't exist.

Comment: Absolute Genius.  Thank you so much.  It's been driving me mad for about a week.